# NSMutableArray thread safety

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety, nsmutablearray

In my app I'm accessing and changing a mutable array from multiple threads. At the beginning it was crashing when I was trying to access an object with `objectAtIndex`, because index was out of bounds (object at that index has already been removed from array in another thread). I searched on the internet how to solve this problem, and I decided to try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521873/2298998) .I made a class with `NSMutableArray` property, see the following code:

```
@interface SynchronizedArray()
@property (retain, atomic) NSMutableArray *array;
@end

@implementation SynchronizedArray

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    @synchronized(_array)
    {
        return [_array objectAtIndex:index];
    }
}

-(void)removeObject:(id)object
{
    @synchronized(_array)
    {
        [_array removeObject:object];
    }
}

-(void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    @synchronized(_array)
    {
        [_array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}

-(void)addObject:(id)object
{
    @synchronized(_array)
    {
        [_array addObject:object];
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)count
{
    @synchronized(_array)
    {
        return [_array count];
    }
}

-(void)removeAllObjects
{
    @synchronized(_array)
    {
        [_array removeAllObjects];
    }
}

-(id)copy
{
    @synchronized(_array)
    {
        return [_array copy];
    }
}
```

and I use this class instead of old mutable array, but the app is still crashing at this line: `return [_array objectAtIndex:index];` I tried also this approach with `NSLock`, but without a luck. What I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you synchronizing access to `[NSMutableArray count]` as well (and every other access to the array)?

Comment: Yes, to all used methods: count, removeObjectAtIndex, addObject etc.

Comment: I edited the question and added the entire class code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this solution is poor.  Consider this:

1. thread #1 calls `count` and is told there are 4 objects in the array.
2. array is unsynchronized.
3. thread #2 calls `removeObjectAtIndex:2` on the array.
4. array is unsynchronized.
5. thread #1 calls `objectAtIndex:3` and the error occurs.

Instead you need a locking mechanism at a higher level where the lock is around the array at both steps 1 and 5 and thread #2 cannot remove an object in between these steps.

Comment: @Euroboy This was a better SO question to have used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091389/nsmutablearray-collection-and-synchronized-blocks

Comment: Yes, I've seen this question before...and I've got inspired  from there. However I tried GCD method too, but the problem persists...I'm confused :(

Comment: I left the method with a class away, and used `@synchronized` directly to my `NSMutableArray`, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to protect (with `@synchronized`) basically all usage of the array. Currently you only prevent multiple threads from concurrently getting objects out of the array. But you have no protection for your described scenario of concurrent modification and mutation.

Ask yourself why you're modifying the array on multiple threads - should you do it that way or just use a single thread? It may be easier to use a different array implementation or to use a wrapper class that always switches to the main thread to make the requested modification.